# Qt delegate module of a QTreeView, delegate non-top widgets only?

Tags: qt4

I use Qt's delegate module for a QTreeView, but this works for both top-level widget and non-top ones, is it possible to control this behavior ? Just delegate for non-top widgets only

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you already know that you can set a delegate for a given column or a given row.  However, the easier way might be to inherit your delegate from whichever Qt one makes sense.  In the delegate functions, you should be able to check the model index's parent and see if it is the same as the tree view's root index.  If it is, it is a top level item, and then you could call the parent class's functions.  Otherwise, implement your own for the non-top level widgets.